leveraging pre-existing dataset
Let say I want to build a model to predict a time series Y. However, the data is only available since 2022. However, there is another time series Z1, Z2, both are correlated to Y, and the data is available since 2007 and 2012 respectively.
What approach I can use to leverage Z1 and Z2 to build a more accurate model of Y?
